# Can't connect to 5GHz network on Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]

Tags: wifi, drivers, manjaro, broadcom

Whenever I try to connect to my 5 GHz network, my KDE Network Manager takes a while on "configuring interface", where then I am prompted to enter a password. I enter the network password, but the whole process repeats. I am running Manjaro Linux, and additional information is below.

### `$ sudo lspci -vvvnnk -d 14e4:`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
        DeviceName: Wireless LAN
        Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:05e2]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
        Region 0: Memory at b2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
        Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
        Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <64us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-b3-ff-ff-d7-30-10
        Capabilities: [16c v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: bcma
```

### `$ iwlist wlp2s0b1 freq`

```
wlp2s0b1  20 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

### Driver

I'm using the `b43` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This card, according to the [Broadcom Wiki](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom), does support only the **abgn** networks.

You probably meant that the **a** stands for **ac**, which is nowadays 5 GHz standard.

I am sorry, but this card simply does not support **ac** networking.

Answer (score 0):

802.11a works on 5 GHz, but basically no AP today offers 802.11a. 802.11n can work both on 2.4GHz and on 5GHz.

So the first thing to check (`iw scan`) is if you indeed have an access point (AP) that is offering 802.11a or 802.11n on 5 GHz. If you have a modern router with 802.11ac (which is totally different from 802.11a), you'll see exactly the symptoms you describe: Your Wifi card will try to connect to the AP so it asks for a password, then it'll negotiate with the AP, but they won't be able to agree on the same standard (the AP tries 802.11ac, your Wifi tries 802.11a or 802.11n).

If you have an AP capable of 802.11a or 802.11n, the next guess is driver/firmware troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem with this exact same card.

The card works on 5GHz bandwidth on a or n mode.

In our case the difficulty appeared some time ago after a change of router that came packed with its set of parameters... That included "DFS" as a default channel selection setting for Wi-Fi a+n+ac on 5GHz bandwidth.
Moving it to channel 40 made the 5GHz Wi-Fi AP accessible by this BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n with B43 mainline driver (>kernel 3.17) + b43 firmwares.

Comment: Just to clarify... only a and n use 5GHz spectrum, and of those only n is in use anymore. b/g work only on 2.4GHz spectrum.

Comment: Also, the reverse-engineered b43 driver seems to support only a limited set of 5GHz channels for the BCM43228 radio chip. I guess the people doing the reverse engineering only got the chip set-up parameters for the channels that were legal to use at their own location, and left the rest for someone else to do.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Well, ac wifi does provides 5GHz band, but this card is not compatible.

Comment: 802.11ac and 802.11n are different standards. ac is backwards compatible with n, but n-devices can't use ac features. I just wanted to point that out to explain why the card only supports 5GHz on a and n, but not on b/g. @telcoM - the chip itself can only support channels that are specified in 802.11n. No amount of reverse engineering can make it support more.

Comment: That was to emphasize that not only 802.11a or 802.11n use 5GHz band but also 802.11ac, because your first comment can be misleading.

Comment: Well ac works _only_ on 5GHz :-) Don't really see how it's relevant to this chipset, tho.

Comment: @Peregrino69 my point is, depending on where you live, the `b43` driver may restrict the 5GHz channel selection even further than the chip itself does, because the driver does not yet know how to tune the chip to all the possible channels. I found this out as my dual-boot system could connect to my 5GHz N WiFi in Windows but not in Linux, until I went to the AP's settings and changed the 5GHz channel to something the `b43` driver could support. The proprietary `wl` driver apparently does not have this problem. (I no longer have that system: if the `b43` driver has been improved, great!)

Comment: @telcoM Yeah, sure, makes perfect sense. I misunderstanded your comment, sorry about that :-)